# pk is passed but data not displayed

Tags: python, html, django, django-views, django-templates

I have a model that contains some judgments along with their title. Now i want to display the judgement when the related title is clicked. i have written the following code:

**models.py**

```py
class Laws(models.Model):
    date= models.DateField(default=timezone.now)
    title= models.CharField(max_length=225, help_text="judgement title")
    judgements= RichTextField(blank=True, null= True)
    law_type= models.CharField(max_length=40, choices= type_of_law)
    law_category= models.CharField(max_length=60, choices= category)
```

**views.py**

```py
class DocView(ListView):
    model= Laws
    template_name = 'doc.html'

class Doc1DetailView(DetailView):
    model= Laws
    template_name = 'doc1.html'
```

**urls.py**

```py
urlpatterns=[
    path('doc', DocView.as_view(), name='doc' ),
    path('doc1/<int:pk>', Doc1DetailView.as_view(), name='doc1' ),
]
```

***and the html files are***
**doc.html**

```
{% for data in object_list %}
                    
    <div class="tab">
        <a href="{% url 'doc1' data.pk %}">{{data.title}}</a><br/> 
    </div>
       
                    
{% endfor %}
```

**doc1.html**

```
<p style="color: black;">{{data.judgements}}</p>
```

I refered to a video in youtube and wrote this code his was working and mine not. i have chamged nothing from that code still the data doesn't show up in doc1.html. No filed is empty here.

please rectify my code and tell me what i am doing wrong here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Laws` object is *not* passed as `data`, but as `object` (and also as `laws`), so you render this with:

```
<p style="color: black;">{{ object.judgements }}</p>
```

---

> **Note**: normally a Django model is given a *singular* name, so `Law` instead of <s>`Laws`</s>.

Comment: thank you so much sir, thsi solved my probelm also i shall rectify the model name to singular